# increasing memory usage with jquery

Tags: jquery, debugging, iframe, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am developing a site which heavily uses jquery (UI) for providing a good user experience. For some (stupid) reason parts of this site are shown within an iframe and there also is a button for refreshing the iframe to get the latest data from the server.

The problem is that each time when refreshing the iframe the memory usage increases leading to serious memory problems after some time (Tested in IE8 & 9). But this occurs only if the jquery library is loaded. This behaviour can be seen best when using [Drip/Sieve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/). For better understanding the problem I stripped off all unnecessary code leading to the two files below. With each reload the memory usage increases about 800 kb. (try http://jsbin.com/asamid/7 if you want to reproduce)

**How can i prevent jquery from eating away my memory? Is there a way to manually unload all jquery before reloading?**

index.htm: (see http://jsbin.com/asamid/7/edit#html,live)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Memory Leak - Parent</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function reload() {
            var frame = document.getElementById("testFrame");
            frame.src = "frame.htm";
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:reload()" id="link">reload frame</a>
    <iframe id="testFrame" src="frame.htm" />
  </body>
</html>
```

frame.htm: (see http://jsbin.com/ocuval/edit#html,live)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Memory Leak - Frame</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Test Frame</h2>
    <div>lorem ipsum</div><div>lorem ipsum</div><div>lorem ipsum</div><div>lorem ipsum</div><div>lorem ipsum</div><div>lorem ipsum</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use ajax to reload the data from the server? This is probably more ideal this way, convert the data to JSON and have jQuery parse it via ajax.

Comment: This problem seems to be related to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865958/iframe-based-ie6-javascript-memory-leak), but not using jquery is not an option.

Comment: @lolwut: The problem is that I don't have jquery within index.htm and I'm worried about breaking the other stuff when including it.

Comment: How about destroying the iframe and creating a new one rather than recyling the same one over and over?

Comment: @jfriend00: just tried that after your comment but with no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with one or more of the following:

- Use an object element instead of an iframe
- Manipulate [$.fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262708/using-jquery-remove-causes-memory-leak#answers-header)
- Create an iframe dynamically using the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#entry-examples-1)