# How can i manually unload the jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, memory

How can i manually unload the jQuery library so that the used memory is freed again?

The actual problem is that I'm loading jquery in an iframe which, after changing the source, keeps jquery in memory and does not free it again. (see  [increasing memory usage with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577322/increasing-memory-usage-with-jquery) for more background information)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to explicitly free up the memory used by jQuery, but one thing you can try would be:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = undefined;
```

**EDIT:** (per Matt's comment):

Even better:

```
delete window.jQuery;
delete window.$;
```

Comment: I guess you mean `null` rather than `nil`. However, you could (*should*) do `delete window.jQuery` and `delete window.$` to recreate the state of `window` before jQuery was added, or at least set them to `undefined`. Neither jQuery or $ was ever `null` before jQuery was added.

Comment: `delete window.jQuery` gives me an error in IE8: "Object does not support this action"