# How to disable JQuery script at or below certain window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var imageswidth = $(window).width() - $('#feature').width() - $('#recommend').width();
        $('#images').css('width', imageswidth);
    });
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        var imageswidth = $(window).width() - $('#feature').width() - $('#recommend').width();
        $('#images').css('width', imageswidth);
    });
</script>
```

How can I disable this script when the **window's width** is **1280px or below**?

Comment: What have you tried? Surely, if you have found `resize` and `window.width()`, you'd know how to piece both together...

Comment: You don't "disable" it, you wrap the contents of the function in an `if` that checks the width.

Comment: get the windows width and height, and then read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587750/how-can-i-manually-unload-the-jquery-library