# using jQuery remove() causes memory leak

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

I have a div in which I frequently create child divs and later remove them. The insert function looks like this.

```
var insert = function(container, content) {
    content = $(content);
    container.append(content);
    return content;
};

var newContent = insert($('#container'), '<div>new content</div>');

// later
newContent.remove();
```

container is a jQuery object. content is a string like `<div>new content</div`>. Later, that new content is removed.

The div is properly removed from the dom, but using chrome's profiling feature, I can see memory grow and grow. The profile shows a list of strings, thousands of which are my deleted content. Tracking it down, I see that jquery has a property called fragments.

`$.fragments` is a map where the key strings are html fragments (literally `<div>new content</div>` is the key string) and the values are DocumentFragment objects.

The DocumentFragment objects contain a property 'native' which contains a value of type 'Detached DOM tree'. And there is my detached object.

It seems like the problem is that jQuery is not flushing this `$.fragments` collection. I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.

One possible reason I could see for this is that the keys of the map are html that was inserted, but by the time I get around to deleting the fragment, I've changed the newContent div's attributes.

One possible solution is to keep a pool of unused new content divs and re-use them. I don't *really* want to do that, but it might be reasonable.

Comment: IF this is true you should probably create an issue for the jQuery team so that it can be addressed. [jQuery bug reporting site](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket?redirectedfrom=)

Comment: If you don't want the divs reused, create elements properly by creating the element, then giving it attributes and content. When you do any of these... `$('<div>') $('<div/>') $('<div></div>')` ...jQuery will use `document.createElement()`. Creating DOM nodes from HTML strings is an ugly practice IMO.

Comment: Why is newContent = $('<div>new content</div>') less proper than newContent = $('<div>').text('new content')?

The more complicated 'new content' gets, the less I'm going to want to run through a gauntlet of setting attributes, styles, and content programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like jQuery is using `$.fragments` to speed up `$("<...>")` then.

I suppose using `$("<div>").html(...)` would not use the cache, but it's obviously semantically different.

You could just try occasionally flushing `$.fragments` yourself and see what happens. I have the gut feeling everything would go just as expected with no ill effects.

I don't think jQuery really has a way to track the fragment cache usage itself, and an LRU cache or somesuch would probably be slower, not to mention more trouble implementing.

Comment: You got it. I just came up to speed on this. The real problem is that I'm creating a short but unique string of HTML every time and jquery is trying to cache that.
I wish I could tell jQuery not to cache it, but I can create the element and fill in the details as a second step.

Comment: As a workaround, you could force `jQuery.support.checkClone` or `jQuery.support.html5Clone` to be false before doing any of this. This'll prevent jQuery from caching the fragments, apparently. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L494

Comment: checkClone worked. Thanks. Taking the unique aspects out of the html fragments as I create them and adding them in later also works. I'll have to think about what am not i am said above.

Comment: I take it back. I had to observe for a longer time period. checkClone + html5Clone did not fix it. The other change did fix it.